# Error insert in a table of a new schema in netbeans

Tags: jpa, netbeans, schema, persistence

I'm working with netbeans 7.1 and a I created a new schema in database sample called TIENDA and I setted it as Default Schema. Then I created a table calle USUARIO with some fields and a field called DIRECCION1. I'm trying to persist a new USUARIO but the application show me this error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'DIRECCION1' no es una columna en la tabla o VTI 'APP.USUARIO'. Error Code: -1
```

Maybe I have to change something in persistence.xml but I dont know what.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate your database as it does not have this column.

See, http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL

Comment: Thank you James for you answer. Finally I found other way to fix it, with JPA anotations like this: http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Table